# Check response from XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I need to check if my xhr request returning me the response as #document, or as an error.

[image]

it can be other errors, like on image above (#403, net:ERR...) 
Well.

I'll attach my code and will tell you where I need the help. 
my function to getHTML.

```
let getHTML = function ( url, callback ) {

// Feature detection
if ( !window.XMLHttpRequest ) return;

// Create new request
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

// Setup callback
xhr.onload = function() {
  if ( callback && typeof( callback ) === 'function' ) {
    callback( this.responseXML );
  }
}

// Get the HTML
xhr.open( 'GET', url );
xhr.responseType = 'document';
xhr.send();

};

const domains = [];
```

and where I need help:

```
getHTML('https://www.brandnames.net/shop/?count=5', function (response) {
    const nodeListDomains = Array.from(response.querySelectorAll( '.product-loop-title' ));
    for(let i=0; i<nodeListDomains.length; i++){
        getHTML(`http://${nodeListDomains[i].text}`, function (response){
           if(response){
               console.log(response)
           }
            **WHAT TO WRITE HERE TO GET ONLY WORKING RESPONSE, BUT NOT ERRORS? AND THE SAME FOR ERRORS, BUT NOT WORKING RESPONSE**
        })
    }
})
```

The main task: My client have a site where he's selling domains(brandnames.net/shop/), and we redirect all of domains to our landing page, but some of domains are not pointing to lander, so I need to check what exactly. Hope you will understand what I tried to tell.

Comment: I can do it in this bad way: 
 `if(typeof response.prototype !== 'undefined'){
           domains.push(nodeListDomains[i])
 }` 

(It's doesn't matter if it's .prototype or anything else) buy I want to find the right solution for this.

Comment: You need to use `onreadystatechange` and not `onload` see [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange)